# Methodology to evaluate any change in android aimed at performance gains

Tags: java, android, performance

When making a change in an android application and wanting to evaluate if it actually improves anything in performance, what are some standard steps to do?
There must be some standard things to check using either Android Studio or MAT.
My main interest is about checking that memory usage has been improved.

**Update:**
Just to clarify. I am not running into some big issue with memory that I need to improve. I am interested in testing with something that I believe will optimize the memory usage but I am not sure how to verify it

Comment: I think this is entirely too broad a question.  There is no right answer.

Comment: @durbnpoisn:How can there be no right answer? A mobile device has specific limitations. E.g. if you do something wrong you use up all the batter. There must be some common accepted things about what to check for performance.

Comment: "How can there be no right answer" -- I'd phrase it as "there is no universal answer". "what are some standard steps to do" -- measure your metrics of concern before the change, make the change, then measure your metrics of concern after the change. However, the details there will vary significantly by what those metrics are and the nature of the app. "memory usage has been improved" -- that's like saying "I want my car to run better". While it's an admirable goal, there is nothing measurable there, and without metrics, you cannot measure improvement.

Comment: @CommonsWare:So how can I measure the metrics of concern before the change if I don't know what are the standards things to check in the app for memory usage and how to check them?

Comment: Well, since I do not know what "memory usage" means to you, and since I do not know anything about your app, I cannot readily provide you with guidance. You may wish to edit your question to provide a detailed description of your app and an explanation of what particularly worries you about "memory usage". Possible definitions of "memory usage" include, but are not limited to: number and frequency of allocations, frequency and duration of GC cycles, heap consumption/avoiding `OutOfMemoryError`, memory management for NDK code, memory leaks, process working set size, and IPC transaction size.

Comment: @CommonsWare:Your comment makes totally sense. I understand your point. But it is not that I am facing some issue in my app. I believe that a certain change will be optimizing memory usage a lot and I want to verify that. Meaning that the app will consume less memory (by not creating too many not needed objects) and GC will be reduced.

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio Device Monitor is the first step to go.

**1)** Check How much memory it is using before and after your change via Android Monitor(memory tab)

**2)** By MAT, check if there can be any code which can cause OOM/MemoryLeak, check before and after change hprof files to understand.

For memory these two options can be checked, other than these, can check CPU/GPU usage as well.

Comment: But how should I interact with the app? How long should I monitor? I notice that when I run a GC in memory tab of Android Studio the memory is released very fast. I am not sure if this is expected.

Comment: It depends on when you start seeing bad memory usage, or why at the first place you made those change, use same feature for same time both before/after change.

Comment: I am not running into some big issue with memory that I need to improve. I am interested in testing with something that I believe will optimize the memory usage but I am not sure how to verify it

Comment: If you do not have memory leaks/ OOM and other memory usages issues, how would you want to optimize it. Optimization comes when one is sure that their code is not running correctly. In terms of memory if you dont know which part of your code is consuming more memory than expected, what would you optimize. If you want, just play around with MAT and your app and see if the behavior of your app is matching the expectations or now?

Comment: You never know if the code that works now, will not be efficient in the long run. The fact that something does not cause any issue now doesn't mean that can not be optimized.

Comment: Optimization is process to re-write/change implementation to make it use less resources(memory for our discussion), if you don't know how much memory it is taking with the current implementation, you won;t be able to check if changes are optimizing the memory or not. You need to have a reference somewhere.